# Layer multiple components in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, components

I am currently creating a platformer game with classes Level and Robot. The classes are incomplete, but here is the basic structure:

```
/**
 * @(#)Robot.java
 *
 * Robot application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2015/5/15
 */

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Robot extends JComponent {

    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private boolean[] skills;
    private boolean[][] collision;
    final private int xa = 1; // Subject to Change
    final private int ya = 1; // Subject to Change
    private final int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

    public Robot() {
        xPos = BLOCK_SIZE*5; // variables for sample level
        yPos = BLOCK_SIZE*21 - 28;
    }

    /* Creates the Robot at the beginning of each stage
    *  Gives the robot skills it can use
    *  Robot receives map of where each block is for collision
    *  @startX and startY: block value
    *  @accessable and map: boolean arrays that are filled
    */
    public Robot(int startX, int startY, boolean[] accessable, boolean[][] map) {
        xPos = startX;
        yPos = startY;
        skills = accessable;
        collision = map;
    }

    // Robot moves laterally right one block
    public void moveRight() {
        if (collision[yPos][xPos + 1] == false) {
            xPos += xa;
        }
    }

    // Robot moves laterally left one block
    public void moveLeft() {
        if (collision[yPos][xPos - 1] == false) {
            xPos -= xa;
        }
    }

    // Robot moves vertically up certain distance
    public void Jump() {
        if (skills[0] == true && collision[yPos - 1][xPos] == false) {
            yPos -= ya;
        }
    }

    // Returns x-position of the robot in block number
    public int getX() {
        return xPos;
    }

    // Returns y-Position of the robot in block number
    public int getY() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Image robot = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("RobotRight.png"); // robot
        g2.drawImage(robot, 28, 28, this);
    }

}
```

The stage is as follows:

```
/**
 * @(#)SampleLevel.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2015/5/15
 */

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SampleLevel extends JComponent /*implements Environment*/ {
    // variables to determine size of blocks being used
    private final int BLOCKS_IN_ROW = 40;
    private final int BLOCKS_IN_COLUMN = 30;
    private final int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

    // the y-value when the black meet the tiles 
    private final int TILE_BORDER = 21;

    public SampleLevel() {

    }

    // work in progress, method may not be needed
    public void fill() {
        ;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("BrickTile.jpg"); // the floor tile
        Image img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("SampleBackground1.jpg"); // black background

        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKS_IN_ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < TILE_BORDER; j++) {
                g2.drawImage(img2, BLOCK_SIZE*i, BLOCK_SIZE*j, this);
                g2.finalize();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKS_IN_ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = TILE_BORDER; j < BLOCKS_IN_COLUMN; j++) {
                g2.drawImage(img1, BLOCK_SIZE*i, BLOCK_SIZE*j, this);
                g2.finalize();
            }
        }

        // testing overlapping images
        g2.drawImage(img1, BLOCK_SIZE*36, BLOCK_SIZE*16, this);
        g2.drawImage(img1, BLOCK_SIZE*24, BLOCK_SIZE*13, this);

    }

}
```

However, I want to add both of these components to a main Viewer class, but the JFrame cannot add two components. Does anyone know a way to layer the Robot component on top of the stage?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to fix your Robot code. Basically the Robot image should always be painted at (0, 0). Then you need to treat your Robot like any Swing component which means you need to give is a size and location. The size would be the size of the image and the location can be variable as you move the Robot around the screen.

Then you need to add the Robot to the Stage.

Somewhere you need code that looks something like:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
SampleLevel stage = new SampleLevel();
stage.add(robot);
frame.add(stage);
```

Now the frame will paint the stage and the state will paint the robot.

Also, you should not read the Robot image in the paintComponent() method. The image should be read once in the constructor. After you read the image you can then set the size of the robot based on the image size.